# How to auto redirect user having Auto-Login cookie, using Auto-Login component in CakePHP 2x?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, remember-me, autologin

I am using CakePHP 2x with Auto-Login component. The problem is, I can write the stuff but, I am not sure how to implement it to read and authorize. When user arrives at the page, he still has the cookie in his browser but, how do I authorize it?

My Login script:

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->Auth->user('id')) {
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'dashboard'));
        }
        if($this->request->data['User']['auto_login']):
        $this->AutoLogin->write($this->request->data['User']['username'],
                $this->request->data['User']['password']);
        endif;

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login( )) {
                //$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect( ));
            }
            else 
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or Password is incorrect'), 'default', array( ), 'auth');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be something like:

```
public function login()
{       
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if ($this->Auth->login())
        {               
            if ($this->request->data['User']['persist'] == '1')
            {
                $cookie = array();
                $cookie['username'] = $this->data['User']['USER_LOGINNAME'];
                $cookie['password'] = $this->data['User']['USER_PASSWORD'];
                $this->Cookie->write('Auth.User', $cookie, true, '+4 weeks');
            }
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your username or password was incorrect.', 'default/flash-error');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $user = $this->Auth->user();
        if (empty($user))
        {
            $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('Auth.User');                             
            if (!is_null($cookie)) 
            {
                $user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('USER_LOGINNAME' => $cookie['username'], 'USER_PASSWORD' => AuthComponent::password($cookie['password']))));
                if ($this->Auth->login($user['User'])) 
                {
                    $this->Session->delete('Message.auth');
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                }
                else 
                { 
                    $this->Cookie->delete('Auth.User');
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you the idea of how to achieve the same task, however, I used form fields according to my DB Structure.

**Kindly change the form fields according to your DB Structure.**

Comment: Woah! that's a huge change. Let me try it out. Please bear with me.

Comment: Your code did get me somewhere (+1) for that. However, just one last query before I close this question is, I am using Facebook plugin for auth (FB Connect), it has a line called Session_start. In my core.php I am using cake as session handler. I saw that autologin is saving cakephp.cookie and also there is phpsessid, when browser dies, it is even deleting the cookies! any ideas on that?

Comment: Try this link: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html#controller-setup

Comment: Above code is working fine on my machine. However, you can also try to make a reverse of: http://kodegeek.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/cakephp-cookie-lifetime-issue/